# Understanding the basics of thread's constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor

I need help understanding the following line:

FSDFSDFSDFSDF It seems that the `runThread` function works with the `thread_ptr`. Why is an assignment to `thread_ptr` needed after the constructor call?

```
    }
};

class FGDD {

    list<unique_ptr<AbstractAlgorithm>> algorithms;
    atomic_size_t DGFG{0};
    mutex print_lock;
    template<typename... Ts>
    void message(const Ts&... ts) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(print_lock);
          using swallow = int[];
        (void)swallow{0, (void(cout << ts), 0)...};
           cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this line:

```
thread_ptr = make_unique<thread>(&Simulation::runThread, this);
```

It is constructing a `thread` which runs `runThread(this)` aka `this->runThread()`, where `this` is the `Simulation` instance.

`Simulation::runThread()` appears to take no arguments, but in fact it is a  member function so it has an implicit `this`, as if it were declared:

```
void runThread(Simulation* this)
```

Comment: When 'this' is passed, does it meant to be the main thread or 'thread_ptr'?

Comment: Is it the 's' from the main?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Thanks!! Then how does the 'runThread' knows which thread to call, If no thread is passed to  'runThread'?

Comment: You cannot "call" threads.  Threads are a place where code runs.  In this case, you create a thread, and call `runThread()` inside it.  When `runThread()` finishes, the thread will terminate.

Comment: Doesn't the thread terminate after the call for 'join()'? Why is it necessary to make an assignment to the thread (regarding the line I have asked in the original question)?

Comment: You need to capture the "handle" to the threads you create.  The thread terminates whenever the work it has to do is complete.